# How can I compress jpegs in Python more efficiently?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pathlib

I'm working with thousands of large image files in a regularly updated library. The following script does the job (on average reduces my file size ~95%) but costs me around 25 seconds to compress one image. Obviously, I can just let the script run overnight, but it would be cool if I can shave some time off this process. I'm mostly looking for any unnecessary redundancies or overhead in the script that can be trimmed out to speed up the process. I'm still new to Python, so go easy on me.

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
import os, sys
import glob

root_dir = "/.../"

basewidth = 3500

for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '*.jpg', recursive=True):
    p = Path(filename)
    img = p.relative_to(root_dir)
    new_name = (root_dir + 'compressed/' + str(img))
    print(new_name)
    im = Image.open(filename)
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(im.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(im.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    im = im.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(new_name, 'JPEG', quality=40)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, a better place to ask might be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can process multiple files in parallel using [the `multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)

Comment: @MikeScotty Gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @ForceBru I'll look into it. Thank you

Comment: PIL isn't known for its speed.  You might look for a different library.

Comment: You can do them very fast, in parallel, in a one-liner from the Terminal if that's an option? Tag me by my name with an `@` in front if so, and I will get notified that you have answered my comment.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'd be interested in hearing more about your terminal command

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can do this without Python, just in the Terminal with **ImageMagick**, which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

It looks like you want to convert a bunch of JPEGs to a width of 3,500 pixels at a quality of 40, correct?

Make a testing directory with 100 or so JPEGs in it - a **COPY** of non-precious files that you can play around and experiment on. This command should convert one single JPEG, so try that first:

```
magick input.jpg -quality 40 -resize 3500x result.jpg
```

If that looks correct, this command will do exactly the same to all the JPEGs in the current directory and save the results in a subdirectory called `processed`:

```
mkdir processed
magick mogrify -path processed -resize 3500x -quality 40 *.jpg
```

If that looks correct, we can parallelise it next.. let me know how it goes.

---

You can also do it with `libvips`. So, to process one image:

```
vipsthumbnail input.jpg -o result.jpg[Q=40] --size 3500x
```

And try that on all 100 images with:

```
for f in *.jpg ; do
    echo "Processing $f"
    vipsthumbnail "$f" -o processed/"$f"[Q=40] --size 3500x
done
```

If that is faster, we can pursue that in parallel.

---

If you are on macOS, you can install **ImageMagick** and **vips** with **homebrew**:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install vips
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I swapped "vips" for "vipsthumbnail" in your example, hope that's OK. vipsthumbnail accepts the 3500x syntax, so it's a better match for this problem.